# How to put multiple tags in codepen post?

Tags: codepen

How can I add multiple tags on codepen.io?

When I use the [write](http://codepen.io/write/) page, in the *Tags* box, I don't understand how to put multiple tags and not only one tag.

Here a screenshot for my problem:

[image: codepen tags]

Like you can see it puts all the tags together (`html css js php tag5 tag6 etc`) rather than listing them separately (`html` `css` `js` `php` `tag5` `tag6` `etc`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to separate them with commas for them to be separated tags, for example: `html, css, js, php, tag5, tag6, etc`

[image: Tags]

Comment: @MattewDeveloper: If this answer solved your problem, please consider using the checkmark to "accept" it. Accepting an answer acts as a signpost to future readers who have the same question. More information in the Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)